# Breeze with second controller

Tags: breeze

I need to get some data from a different database (different server, actually), so I've created a second datacontext pointing to a second Breeze controller, repository, and edmx.  I also created second model and entityManagerFactory since data I'll need to be getting is substantial and wanted to separate it from the base functionality. In my new EntityManagerFactory, if I have:

```
breeze.NamingConvention.none.setAsDefault();
```

all works well, but I don't get camel casing. If I have:

```
breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
```

or if I don't call it at all (since it's just setting the app-wide default which is already set) I get this error:

[myDatacontext] [HT Error] Error retrieving dataMetadata query failed for: breeze/Vsp/Metadata. Unable to either parse or import metadata: NamingConvention for this server property name does not roundtrip properly:name-->Name; [object Object]Error: Metadata query failed for: breeze/Vsp/Metadata. Unable to either parse or import metadata: NamingConvention for this server property name does not roundtrip properly:name-->Name; [object Object]

There's not even a "name" or "Name" property on class I'm getting.

What am I missing?

By the way, I do get the metadata from the server. The client just doesn't like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that since you've posted this you found a solution.
But I also had this problem, it is because I use Entity-Framework ADO .Net 6.0, it takes into account stored procedure, views or tables that are not camelcase, so you have to unselect them before generating the model / context.

Comment: No, I never did solve it until I saw your post. That was it fguigui. I just included everything when I generated the edmx. Thanks!